# filter list by condition using python

Tags: python, performance

```
def myFunction(cond_list, input_list):
    res = []
    data = list(set(input_list))  # filter duplicate elements
    for i in cond_list:
        for j in data:
            if i in j:
                res.append(i)
    return res

cond = ['cat', 'rabbit']  
input_list = ['', 'cat 88.96%', '.', 'I have a dog', '', 'rabbit 12.44%', '', 'I like tiger']
result = myFunction(cond_list=cond, input_list=input_list)
print(result)  # the input list have: ['cat', 'rabbit']
```

I have a function. Is there any better way to modify my function according to the conditions?

Comment: What do you want your function to do? Can you share some sample inputs and outputs ?

Comment: Is the expected output `['cat 88.96%', 'rabbit 12.44%']` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh no,get the string I setting --> ['cat', 'rabbit']

Comment: So if your input and output are same? What is the function doing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, is this what you are looking for?

```
cond = ['cat', 'rabbit']  # filter duplicate elements
input_list = ['', 'cat 88.96%', '.', 'dog 40.12%', '', 'rabbit 12.44%', '', 'tiger 85.44%']
[i for i in cond for j in input_list if i in j]
```

> ['cat', 'rabbit']

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the pairs for comparison:

```
>>> product = itertools.product(cond, input_list)
>>> [p for (p, q) in product if p in q]
['cat', 'rabbit']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cond = ['cat', 'rabbit']  # filter duplicate elements
input_list = ['', 'cat 88.96%', '.', 'dog 40.12%', '', 'rabbit 12.44%', '', 'tiger 
85.44%']
matching = list(set([s for s in input_list if any(xs in s for xs in cond)]))

for i in matching: 
   print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using regex and a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
import re

def myFunction(cond_list, input_list):
    data = set(input_list)  # filter repeat element
    pattern = re.compile("|".join(data))
    return [i for i in cond_list if pattern.search(i)]

cond = ['cat', 'rabbit']  # filter duplicate elements
input_list = ['', 'cat 88.96%', '.', 'dog 40.12%', '', 'rabbit 12.44%', '', 'tiger 85.44%']
result = myFunction(cond_list=cond, input_list=input_list)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['cat', 'rabbit']
```